# Logback prudent file appender versus socket appender

Tags: logback

We are considering logging into one file from multiple nodes of our cluster. Cluster shares NAS so we have multiple options.

Logback comes with file appender that has prudent mode that ensure locking and so, but it comes at the cost of performance - this is discussed in the manual http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender

Other option is SocketAppender and the SimpleSocketServer. Performance of this solution is not discussed there.

What would be the most efficient way to handle that?

Comment: We use SimpleSocketServer and haven't noticed performance issues.

Comment: At what scale? how many servers and log messages?

Comment: The scale is small. (Our sites are used inside single business-departments). On our sub-net, we have 7 socket servers. Each receives an average of about 5 to 10 messages per minute from a pair of Tomcat nodes (so, 7 socket appenders and 14 Tomcats). At peak, a particular appender may be receiving about 50-100 messages a minute. 
In addition, we have a central Socket appender which is only sent ERRORs. All 14 Tomcats can send messages there. In addition, another 12-15 stand-alone Tomcats send messages there too. Since these are only errors, even adding eveything up, the volume is neglible.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an easy way out, then I would prefer a FileAppender.

A more robust setup is with SocketAppender and the SimpleSocketServer, but this needs a (relative) more complex setup.